# Google Chrome Extension to handle certain links

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hyperlink, url-scheme

I need to create a simple Chrome extension that will open telephone links in Gmail with a certain application (Cisco Jabber) instead of the default (Google Hangouts).

I've tried doing some research and haven't found anything that indicates this is possible. Is this something that a Chrome extension can do? If so, can someone point me in the right direction on how to get started, please?

Comment: Google provides special preferential treatment inside Chrome source code for its own extensions like Hangouts. Isn't it great? It's not of course, but *c'est la vie*. For mere mortals the only method, AFAIK, is for the external program to install a protocol handler and hope that Chrome will recognize it and offer to use, which it should usually do.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.